# Parameter extraction from a spectrum

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, regression, model-fitting

Let's say for a plant leaf I have a spectrum from 400-1000nm with parameters like temperature, moisture, sunlight, soil. Now I have multiple samples with different leaves with respective parameter values and a spectrum for each. Once I have this database, now I would like to extrapolate the values of temperature, moisture, sunlight and soil for an unknown leaf spectra by comparing with the database.

What would be the right way to find the parameter values?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the data all from the same plant species?

Comment: yes, i.e. there is a coorelation between different parameters for example - increased moisture correlates to a redshift in a spectral peak and temperature causes a red shift.

Comment: Could you model spectral peaks (and valleys) only, rather than the entire spectrum? I think that would simplify the problem, and still provide red shift information. In theory an individual spectrum could easily be scanned for that information before regression.

Comment: There are multiple peaks and features in the spectrum with both intensity and wavelength shift. Since I have so many spectra in the training set, I don't want to manually specify peaks as then I'd have to manually set weights. It would be easier and more robust to compare the entire spectrum which has more information which should help when regressing to get the parameter values

Comment: Would you please post a link to one or two individual spectra? I think I could make a automated "oeak isolator" in Python for you to try.